# Atom　localizationでの日本語化ができない　Windows7

Tags: windows, atom-editor

結論から言うと、

**どうしたらAtomの日本語化ができるのでしょうか？**

AtomをWindows7の環境にインストールしました。
そしてメニューの日本語化のためlocalizationプラグインをインストールし再起動したのですが
日本語化になりません。

そもそもメニューの[Packages]に[localization]が表示されていません。
調べたところ、Windowsではreplaceする文言がマッチしていないため、できなかったという記事もありました。

**Windowsではできないのでしょうか？

また他の方法によって日本語化できる方法はあるでしょうか？**

わかる方お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

次のリンク先のプラグインを利用して解決したいと思います
https://github.com/hinaloe/Atom-Localization/archive/patch-2.zip

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

[この json ファイル](https://github.com/hinaloe/Atom-Localization/blob/patch-2/i18n/win32/japanese.json) を、atom の config フォルダ以下にある

`.atom/packages/localization/i18n/japanese.json`

に上書きすると、多少マシになります。
後はご自身で `japanese.json` を編集して、より良い日本語環境にしてみるといいと思います.

Comment: Shironeさん
コメントありがとうございました。